# Automatic restart of the rails server on exception in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment

Is there any utility to restart a rails server automatically in case of exception occurred i.e. `forever` is the utility through which `node.js` can be started automatically.

Comment: @dimakura any help on this.

Comment: just use [passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/)

Comment: @dimakura Any open source utility or gem would be appreciated rather than enterprise solution.

Comment: It has good open source license too. I use it for > 6 years already. both nginx and apache. and it's great.

Comment: see here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/

Comment: Can you please give me a example how do you use it to restart your rails server in case of exception or failure.

Comment: its done automatically. nothing on my part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89731/discussion-between-naresh-and-dimakura).

Comment: i even deployed nodejs project on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) for production deployments of your Rails applications. It's already a battle tested Rails solution, which is known for simplicity and good reliability. You don't need to worry about crashes, which will be handled automatically.

It provides integration with Apache and Nginx servers.

It also comes with free (community) license.

Enterprise edition gives you more feature, like uninterrupted deployments and rollbacks to last stable version.

They claim [usage on 350,000 websites](http://trends.builtwith.com/Web-Server/Phusion-Passenger). So you will be in a good company.